# How to show a Navigation Label instead of a Page Title on a Wordpress custom menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a custom menu in Wordpress, I've registered it:

```
function theme_features() {
  register_nav_menu('header_menu', 'Header Menu');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_features');
```

and I'm showing it in the front-end:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                     'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
                     'menu_class' => 'navbar__ul',
                  )); 
?>
```

Then I'm creating the menu in Wordpress admin panel and all is working, the only problem is that when I create an item as such:

[image: screenshot of a wordpress dashboard]

on the front-end I am getting the page title and not the navigation label I've set:

[image]

I've been searching for hours now, if you have any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I did not connect the menu with the position in the right tab:

[image]

I'll leave this here in case someone has the same problem.